# Where can I find the semicolon on the japanese iPhone keyboard

Tags: discussion

So I am currently trying to learn Japanese and adapting to the keyboard on the smartphone, but I really have trouble finding the semicolon. Could someone please enlighten me?

(using apple's stock japanese (hiragana) keyboard)

Comment: It depends entirely on which App you are using for your keyboard, so no one can reply to this unless you provide us with more details.

Comment: I am not using any app. I am using the stock japanese keyboard you can install on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not on the kana keyboard. Is this something that comes up often? The semicolon isn't Japanese punctuation.

If you need the semicolon often and don't want the hassle of switching keyboards, there is a semicolon on the iPhone romaji keyboard, or you might look for a third-party keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. I thought since programming uses semicolons quite heavily they might also have it but they would probably just use an American keyboard for things like that anyway.